# Where to download phonetic word list for Dutch/ Nederlandse fonetische woordenlijst downloaden

Tags: phonetics, ipa, dictionary, dutch

I cannot find phonetic word lists / dictionaries online for Dutch.
Please provide me with a url.
What do you use?
What is available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All words have fonetic writing here:

https://www.woorden.org/woord/woord

Looks like you'll need to scrape the website to create a list.

Answer (score 1):

Wiktionary has IPA for many Dutch words.
If you're looking for a list of basic words with an English spelling based phonetic representation, https://www.dummies.com/languages/dutch-for-dummies-cheat-sheet/ could help you